# Sketch: Quick-Export tries to create PDF instead of PNG

Tags: export, sketch-app, png

in Sketch, when you select an exportable artboard you get a little preview in your inspector panel. Dragging this preview out gives lets you export it, however for some reason Sketch tries to export some of my artboards as pdf instead of png. It also wont let me drag it onto my desktop of anywhere else.

[image: gif showing aforementioned behaviour]

I guess this is some sort of setting you can do per artboard, but I cannot find where to change this behaviour. If you could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I found out thanks to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sketchapp/comments/711e6q/how_to_change_what_filetype_is_being_created_when/?st=J81PGM8R&sh=16424556https://www.reddit.com/r/sketchapp/comments/711e6q/how_to_change_what_filetype_is_being_created_when/?st=J81PGM8R&sh=16424556) sketch fails to export due to there being a slash in the art board name.

So simply removing all slashes from the art board name solves the problem.